# Removing a random item from a list

Tags: python, list, random, sample

As the title says: how to you remove a random item from a list?
I am making text based game, and I have a list in which I want to randomly take an item from and then remove it from the list, as seen below:

```
Deck = ['Lumina, Lighsworn Summoner', 'Lumina, Lighsworn Summoner', 'Judgment Dragon', 'Judgment Dragon', 'Judgment Dragon', 'Jain, Lightsworn Paladin', 'Ehren, Lightsworn Monk', 'Lyla, Lightsworn Sorceress', 'Lyla, Lightsworn Sorceress', 'Ryko, Lighsworn Hunter', 'Ryko, Lighsworn Hunter', 'Ryko, Lighsworn Hunter', 'Celestia, Lightsworn Angel', 'Aurkus, Lightsworn Druid', 'Garoth, Lightsworn Warrior', 'Garoth, Lightsworn Warrior', 'Lightray Gearfried', 'Lightray Gearfried', 'Lightray Gearfried', 'Lightray Daedalus', 'Lightray Daedalus', 'Lightray Daedalus', 'Lightray Diabolos', 'Lightray Diabolos', 'Lightray Diabolos', 'Sephylon, the Ultimate Timelord', 'Sephylon, the Ultimate Timelord', 'Sephylon, the Ultimate Timelord', 'Card Trooper', 'Card Trooper', 'Honest', 'Gorz the Emissary of Darkness', 'Necro Gardna', 'Necro Gardna', 'Necro Gardna', 'Charge of the Light Brigade', 'Solar Recharge', 'Solar Recharge', 'Solar Recharge', 'Beckoning Light', 'Beckoning Light']
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
    option = raw_input()
    if option == 'draw':
        newcard = random.sample(Deck, 1)
        print newcard
        Deck.remove(newcard)
```

However, when I try the in-game 'command' "draw", I always get this output and list-related error:

```
draw
['Judgment Dragon']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "YGOGame.py", line 183, in <module>
    Deck.remove(newcard)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you know you can easily make multi-line Python strings with `"""` tripple-quoted strings? You can use newlines in them..

Comment: Also, you don't really want to use a new variable name for each character in your game. You want to use a dictionary: `characters = {"Lumina": "Lumina, Lighsworn Summoner", "JD": "Judgment Dragon", "Jain": "Jain, Lightsworn Paladin"}`. Then access each one like `characters["JD"]` to get `"Judgment Dragon"` etc.

Comment: Tim, I was going to do that. It's just that I wanted to condense it as I go along for debugging purposes.

Comment: You've already accepted Martijn's answer (which is fine), but probably even closer to what you *really* want is the `.pop` method (instead of selecting and removing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`newcard` is a *list* (you used `random.sample(Deck, 1)`, which returns a list); use:

```
Deck.remove(newcard[0])
```

or use `random.choice()` to pick *one* element:

```
newcard = random.choice(Deck)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for. I would ^1 if could :)