# Select element from a list randomly and update the list again

Tags: python, list, random, updates

I have a list and I would like to select an element in the list randomly. After selecting this element, this list will be updated by removing this element by using Python

For example:

Input:

```
list = [2,3,4,5]
```

Process: randomly select 3

Output:

```
list = [2,4,5]
```

Comment: Hi. Is there a question?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing a random item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076013/removing-a-random-item-from-a-list)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide detailed information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please read [ask] and its linked resources

Comment: @KangDongHo were you able to get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

lst = [2,3,4,5]
k=random.choice(lst)
lst.remove(k)
print('Random number selected is: ', k)
print('remaining list is: ', lst)

#output
Random number selected is  4
remaining list is:  [2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should find random element and remove

the random function should find a random element and return it and the remove function will remove it

```py
import random

lst = [2,3,4,5]

print(lst)

lst.remove(random.choice(lst))

print(lst)
```

Comment: This answer is already present. Also, please **do not** use `list` as a variable name

Comment: Yes but this way is more concise and I wanted to keep the variable name the same as the ones provided. But I'll keep it in mind.
Plus there was no answer when I wrote it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is a time difference of 8 minutes between by answer and your answer. This is not the way it works. Keeping the `list` variable name will override default `list`- data structure.

Comment: thank you for the welcome
ok updated with last.
This way is still better than the one you presented. Regardless of how quick it was to reply (as mentioned there was no answer while I was writing the reply regardless of how long it actually was.)

Comment: There can be multiple answers that can be submitted and the process of people upvoting them is what dictates what is the correct answer or the better application.
This whole "Only have 1 answer" isn't how things work. If it was meant to be that way then all submissions would stop once one answer is given. Yes, the difference is minimal but no less valid.